# In the ui-router-extras demo, I want to use ng-grid in module1 but it's not working

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-router-extras

In my project, I hope the lazy loaded modules can add their own state, so I found the [ui-router-extras](https://github.com/christopherthielen/ui-router-extras). It's really useful for me, but when I want to use ng-grid in the lazy loaded module like the module1 in demo, the module1.js file looks like this:

```
 define(['angularAMD', 'ngGrid'], function () {

     var app = angular.module("module1", ['ui.router','ngGrid']);

     ...
```

and the main.js file looks like this:

```
require.config({
  waitSeconds: 100,
  paths: {
    "angularAMD": "../../lib/angularAMD",
    ...
    "jQuery": "../../lib/jquery",
    "ngGrid": "../../lib/ng-grid-2.0.14.debug"
  },
  shim: {
    "angular": { exports: "angular" },
    ...
    "ngGrid": ["angular", "jQuery"],
  },
  deps: ["app"]
});
```

But I got an exception from ng-grid : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'factory' of undefined". I found the ng-grid source code where the exception happened:

```
angular.module('ngGrid.services').factory('$domUtilityService',['$utilityService', '$window', function($utils, $window) {....}
```

So I found in the lazy loaded module, get module by angular.module('mymodule') returns the undefined. Is there something I forgot to write, or is there another way to use ng-grid or other plugin in the lazy load module with ui-router-extras future?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the '`ngload`' plugin for AngularAMD to load a module on the fly.

Excerpt from the docs:

---

## 3rd Party AngularJS Modules

3rd party AngularJS modules, meaning any module created using angular.module syntax, can be loaded as any normal JavaScript file before angularAMD.bootstrap is called. After bootstraping, any AngularJS module must be loaded using the included ngload RequireJS plugin.

```
define(['app', 'ngload!dataServices'], function (app) {...});
```

In case you need to load your module using the RequireJS plugin or if you have complex dependecies, you can create a wrapper RequireJS module as below:

```
define(['angularAMD', 'ui-bootstrap'], function (angularAMD) {
    angularAMD.processQueue();
});
```

In this case, all dependencies will be queued up and when .processQueue() is called, it will go through the queue and copy them into current app using app.register:

---

https://github.com/marcoslin/angularAMD

Comment: i have resolve this problem , the angularAMD js file in ui-router-extras demo has some error, so just get the new angularAMD.